# Telerik RadWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I'm facing some issues with Telerik Themes in WPF
I have added reference to Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows8 and merged the resources using the file App.xaml with the following code:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows8;component/Themes/System.Windows.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows8;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows8;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows8;component/Themes/telerik.windows.controls.docking.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now I want to apply the Windows 8 Style to my main windows, so I changed it to a telerik:RadWindow

```
<telerik:RadWindow
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
        x:Class="Foo.MainWindow"
        Header="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,79,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <telerik:RadSlider HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="273,156,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
        <telerik:RadButton Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Margin="158,232,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
    </Grid>
</telerik:RadWindow>
```

In the designer the theme is applied and anything looks ok:
[image: IMG]
 but when I start the application it looks totally different:
[image: IMG]

I have no idea why this error occurs.
If I use the code to create a RadWindow it works perfectly:

```
RadWindow w = new RadWindow();
w.Width = 500;
w.Height = 500;
w.Show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think as you're using implicit styles you need to state that your window style is based on the implicit styles you've imported.  Add this inside your `RadWindow` XAML:

```
<telerik:RadWindow.Style>
    <Style TargetType="telerik:RadWindow" BasedOn="{StaticResource RadWindowStyle}" />
</telerik:RadWindow.Style>
```

Alternatively add this to your resource dictionary (`local:MainWindow` should resolve to `Foo.MainWindow`):

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource RadWindowStyle}" TargetType="local:MainWindow" />
```

Here are some links that may prove useful:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/show-radwindow-with-implict-style
http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/wpf/window/details/how-to-use-radwindow-as-main-window

Comment: Thank you so much. I added your code and edited the App.xaml file with [this](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/wpf/window/details/how-to-use-radwindow-as-main-window) tutorial and then it worked..